# First time audio recoding permission get issue

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
11-07 20:30:16.294 12438-12438/com.main.sample W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)

11-07 20:30:16.294 12438-12438/com.main.sample W/System.err:     at com.main.sample.Activity.EventsaddActivity.initializeMediaRecord
```

Comment: which version of SDK and android you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In the first step you need to add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

set target sdk to 22 or use request permission and set target to 23 or above.

and check your path again

```
MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(new File("YOUR_PATH"));
```